# When user goes in unvalidated user's list?

Tags: elgg

I am developing website using elgg. I want to know when user goes in the list of unvalidated user, which is the page of 'Uservalidationbyemail' plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: Which Elgg Version are you Using

Answer (score 0):

The user will go in the "unvalidated" user list, when he/she signups for your site, and doesn't verifies his/her email address.

Thanks